# Add custom html between two model fields in Django admin's change_form

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Let's say I've two models:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    library = models.ForeignKeyField('Library')

class Library(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)   
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)  
    tel = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Is there a nice way to add some html(a readonly input field) between name and address in the Library change_form template?. I'm doing it overriding [admin/includes/fieldset.html](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/includes/fieldset.html) but it's getting messy and I can't find a way to display the html exactly where I want to. For example, if I want to add html displaying the amount of books that the library has below the name field I woul do this:

```
{% for field in line %}
    ...
    {% if field.field.name == 'name' %}
        {{ field.field }}
        <div class="form-row total_books">
            <div>
                <label for="total_books">Total books:</label>
                <input type="text" maxlength="10" name="totbooks" id="totbooks" readonly="readonly">
            </div>
       </div>
    {% else %}
        {{ field.field }}
    {% endif %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

**New solution:**

I've found a nicer way I think, but I don't know why am I getting  this error: "PresupuestoAdmin.readonly_fields[1](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/includes/fieldset.html), 'name' is not a callable or an attribute of PresupuestoAdmin' or found in the model 'Presupuesto' ". It seems that the 'name' field is not added to the form used by the admin.

```
class FoooAdminForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100) 
    class Meta: 
        model = Foo 

class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): 
    form = FooAdminForm 
    fieldsets = ( 
        (None, { 'fields': ('id', 'name', 'date')}), 
    ) 
    readonly_fields = ('id', 'name') 

admin.site.register(Foo, FooAdmin)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class FooAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, 
                widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly': 'readonly'}))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        super(FooAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['name'].required = False
        if kwargs.has_key('instance'): 
            instance = kwargs['instance'] 
            # do something with the instance here if you want 

    class Meta:
        model = Foo

class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = FooAdminForm

    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('id', 'name',),})
    )
    readonly_fields = ('id',)
```

Answer (score 12):

*models.py:*

```
class Library(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)   
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)  
    tel = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def book_count(self):
      return self.book_set.count()
```

*admin.py:*

```
class LibraryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): 
    fieldsets = ( 
        (None, { 'fields': ('name', 'book_count', 'address', 'tel' )}), 
    ) 
    readonly_fields = ('book_count',) 

admin.site.register(Library, LibraryAdmin)
```

Answer (score 3):

This might not give you exactly what you need, but you can override the widget for the field `bar` in model `Foo` by adding this to your `admin.py`:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin import site
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AdminTextInputWidget
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from models import Foo

class AdminFooWidget(AdminTextInputWidget):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        s = super(AdminTextInputWidget, self).render(name, value, attrs)
        return mark_safe(s+u'<br/><b>Hello world!</b>')

class FooAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FooAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['bar'].widget = AdminFooWidget()

class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = FooAdminForm     

site.register(Foo, FooAdmin)
```

Comment: Thanks Udi, I think the solution I posted might be cleaner.

Comment: I added a much better solution ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239966/add-custom-html-between-two-model-fields-in-django-admins-change-form/6343271#6343271 )... (ahm... should I down vote my previous answer now?)